# Remove points with 0 density (no data) in stat_density_2d(geom = 'point')

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes, one which I want to make a stat_density_2d plot using a 'raster' geom and one in which I want to use a 'point' geom. For the point geom I want to remove any point where there is no data though, as measured by a point size of 0.

The following is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

#tibble for raster density plot
df <- tibble(x = runif(1000000, min = -7, max = 5),
             y = runif(1000000, min = 0, max = 1000))

#tibble for point density plot
df2 <-  tibble(x = runif(20000, min = -2, max = 2),
               y = runif(20000, min = 0, max = 500))

#create the density plot
p1 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(data = df, aes(fill = stat(density)), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="transparent", high="red") +
  stat_density_2d(data = df2, geom = "point", aes(size = ..density..), n = 40, contour = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=18)) +
  ylim(0, 1000) + xlim(-7, 5)

p1
```

which returns:

[image]

But where the points are smallest (outside the bounds specified in the df2 tibble) I don't want any density points to be shown. Is there anyway to remove these?

Comment: I'd set the breaks/colors manually with "transparent" (`#00000000`) and set a small tolerance for "too low".

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I go about a small tolerance argument?

Comment: What is "too small"? If you're talking density, then we're talking about floating-point, in which case you should not just compare with 0 ([R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and IEEE-754), you should instead look for densities below a certain number (e.g., `1e-8`, context-sensitive).

Comment: Too small in this case is anything which is being plotted currently but does not actually exist in df2 if that makes sense. So anything outside -2,2 and 0,500, but just for the points not the raster

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood initially. I don't think my answer is "awesome", but it might be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hack, though I don't know how robust it is to differences in data.

BLUF: add `scale_radius(range=c(-1,6))`.

I reduced your data *a lot* so that it doesn't take 5 minutes to render.

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(x = runif(1000, min = -7, max = 5),
             y = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1000))
df2 <-  tibble(x = runif(20, min = -2, max = 2),
               y = runif(20, min = 0, max = 500))
```

Four plots:

1. Your code (my data), no other change;
2. `scale_radius()`;
3. `scale_radius(range = c(-0.332088004, 6))`; and
4. `scale_radius(range = c(-1, 6))`.

[image: four plots]

This is surely a hack, and I don't know how to find a more precise way of filtering out specific levels.

The modified code:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(data = df, aes(fill = stat(density)), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="transparent", high="red") +
  stat_density_2d(data = df2, geom = "point", aes(size = ..density..), n = 40, contour = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  # scale_radius() +
  # scale_radius(range = c(-0.332088004, 6)) +
  scale_radius(range = c(-1, 6)) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=18)) +
  ylim(0, 1000) + xlim(-7, 5)
```